# using the loop with a custom table

Tags: page-template, loop

I have a table in my WordPress db called wp_featuredposts. How can I make a query to output the posts in that table into the loop on a custom wordpress page template?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to query the database and then insert them into [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) (loop.php).